# How to remove element from unordered_set without elements being freed

Tags: c++, pointers, unordered-set

As the title says, I want to remove elements from an `unordered_set` without it's destructors being called. In my case, I'm storing a collection of `MyObject` pointers in an unordered set, however I also want to remove them from the unordered set without them being freed/cleaned up. When calling `erase` however, the elements are automatically freed. Are there any ways to achieve this without having to resort to shared/smart pointers?

Edit: Turns out the memcheck tool did not correctly detect the memory freeing/usage leading to a faulty conclusion and this question.
*Pointers do not get freed upon calling erase on an unordered_set!*

Comment: I'm surprised that the removed element gets freed.   You're storing pointers, so "erase" would call the destructor (not delete) on the erase element, and that's a no-op for a pointer.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? and what is your code? https://wandbox.org/permlink/CSoHDqmEMNd2QOkW

Comment: Show some code. Just removing a raw pointer from `unordered_set` won't destroy the object pointed to. Do you have a collection of smart pointers? You could move from the element before erasing it. Anyway, don't leave us guessing, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: No, calling `erase` on an unordered set of plain pointers does ***not*** delete the objects that they're pointing to. C++ does not work this way, perhaps you are referring to `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, in which case it's a wholy different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `extract` the node that contains the element without destroying the element of the set.

> I'm storing a collection of MyObject pointers

In this case, how about considering just making a copy of the pointer before erasing it from the set?